# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFirstStageObserver>

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Such logs pop up. Anyone know what this is caused by? It doesn't crash the app for me, but it's annoying.. I search everywhere but found nothing.

```
09-24 09:41:56.534 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.534 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.535 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFirstStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.535 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFirstStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.535 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFirstStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.540 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.540 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableLastStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.540 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableLastStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.540 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableLastStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.546 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.546 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableSingleStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.547 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableSingleStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.547 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableSingleStageObserver>
09-24 09:41:56.575 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.576 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.576 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFirstStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.576 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFirstStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.576 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFirstStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.579 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.579 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableLastStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.579 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableLastStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.579 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableLastStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.585 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.586 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableSingleStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.587 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableSingleStageSubscriber>
09-24 09:41:56.587 32761-32761/com.aclaspolska.securedatabase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableSingleStageSubscriber>
```

It coused when I use RxJava3 with Retrofit. Here is the code:

```
// -------------
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            // set your desired log level
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            // -------------
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
                    .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true)
                    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                    .callTimeout(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(connectionSpec))
//                    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
                    .build();

            Retrofit producerServer = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(Constants.PRODUCER_BASE_URL_2)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            RepoService producerService = producerServer.create(RepoService.class);
            producerService.getProducerResponse().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new Observer<Response<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(@NonNull Response<String> stringResponse) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onNext: producer: " + stringResponse.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: completed");
                        }
                    });
```

here some text becouse it has not enought text, details, details
here some text becouse it has not enought text, details, details
here some text becouse it has not enought text, details, details

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?

Comment: No, still the same